# How to use the new FirebaseCrash/upload-sym?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have created new iOS project and in the process of integrating it with Firebase Core and Crash. I have the following run script"

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/path/to/my-json-file"
```

This was working fine on my previous projects, I have checked my old projects and they are fine.

However, the new project seems to have a `upload-sym` from `Pod` `FirebaseCrash` which does not expect arguments.

I have also confirmed that the `upload-sym` file in my older projects is different from the `upload-sym` file in my freshly created project.

How to use `upload-sym` without supplying the path to my json file?

Comment: can you write your firebase  pod file which you are using

Comment: @Lalitkumar My pods are `pod 'Firebase/Core'` and `pod 'Firebase/Crash'`

Comment: Check this https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseCrash

Comment: @Lalitkumar It say that `upload-sym ` should take no arguments. Ok, but when I build my app, it will ask me for json file. I want to automatically supply the json file just like previous versions. or just like as documented on Firebase documentation which I think is outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readme for the FirebaseCrash pod that suggests upload-sym does not take an argument is *incorrect*.  It does require your service account file path as shown in the [docs on the website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios).  Look at the upload-sym script itself in the FirebaseCrash pod directory to verify for yourself what it does.  The latest version of the pod at the time I write this is 1.1.4.